# Float:right is limited by its parent div, making it align right/go down a line

Tags: html, css, alignment

I'm trying to get a toolbar div, with the left div aligned on the left and the right div aligned on the very right of the screen.

I've tried setting a fixed divider setting for the parent divider, but none of the methods exactly seem intuitive. I can't use `100vw` for the parent div since there's a toolbar on the left.

```css
.dashboard_secondary_toolbar{
    /* display:inline-block; */
    flex: 1;
}

.dashboard_secondary_toolbar_left{
    float: left;
}

.dashboard_secondary_toolbar_right{
    float: right;
}
```

```html
<div class = "dashboard_secondary_toolbar">
    <div class = "dashboard_secondary_toolbar_left">
        <p> align me left </p>
    </div>
    <div class = "dashboard_secondary_toolbar_right">
        <p> align me right </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Note that your example is missing a `"` in `class = "dashboard_secondary_toolbar` and adding it back changes the outcome of your example.

Comment: @j08691 Thanks, I had to rewrite it instead of copy & paste since I had a lot of things inbetween the code. It's edited now, should be working to not work.

Comment: Consider switching to flex, it's much easier and more powerful: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just use flex instead of float each div

```css
.dashboard_secondary_toolbar {
  display: flex;
  flex: 1;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
```

```html
<div class="dashboard_secondary_toolbar">
  <div class="dashboard_secondary_toolbar_left">
    <p> align me left </p>
  </div>
  <div class="dashboard_secondary_toolbar_right">
    <p> align me right </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve it using **FlexBox**.

```
<div class="dashboard_secondary_toolbar">
    <p> align me left </p>
    <p> align me right </p>
</div>
```

styles:

```
.dashboard_secondary_toolbar {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
}
```

Nowadays you do not really use "**float**" anymore.

Answer (score -1):

You don't need float, just use display: flex; instead of display: inline-block;

Comment: It doesn't change anything. Did remove it though, thanks.

Comment: here is the working example https://jsfiddle.net/chille1987/s57yrtnf/1/